# False error "The project description file (.project) is missing"

Tags: java, eclipse

### The problem

I have the `.project` file it wants but I still get the error in Java Eclipse when trying to open an old project.

*Picture of the error :* https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rnC4.jpg

*Picture of the project's files :* https://i.stack.imgur.com/caLlM.jpg

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create new workspace and open project

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like the correct place for the .project file.

The .project file must be in the project folder - MDKExample in your case.

Comment: my project folder is the main folder of the forge mod creator(Im creating a minecraft mod so the project folder is the main folder created by forge SDK), and forge SDK created a folder named "eclipse" for those who are coding in eclipse so the ".project" was located from the start in the "eclipse" folder and it worked fine till I didnt touch it for a while, so I dont know why now it issues the ".project" if it used to work properly before when the file was located in the same place